# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the (?). Please make sure that the argument PatientProfileRepository at index [0]

Tags: typescript, testing, nestjs

### background

When passing test code with ci while creating a program with nest.js

I got this error

```
expect(received).toBeDefined()

Received: undefined


Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ProfilesService (?). Please make sure that the argument PatientProfileRepository at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context.
```

### Problems, unknown points

```
describe('ProfilesService', () => {
  let service: ProfilesService

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [ProfilesService],
    }).compile()

    service = module.get<ProfilesService>(ProfilesService)
  })

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined()
  })
})
```

Controller has similar code

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing'
import ProfilesController from './profiles.controller'

describe('Profiles Controller', () => {
  let controller: ProfilesController

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [ProfilesController],
    }).compile()

    controller = module.get<ProfilesController>(ProfilesController)
  })

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(controller).toBeDefined()
  })
})
```

I don't know why controller and service are responsible for undefind.
I'm glad if anyone can tell me.
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just didn't use anything that depended

```
providers: [
 {
    provide: ProfilesService,
    useValue: {},
 },
]
```

```
providers: [
 ProfilesService,
 {
    provide: getRepositoryToken(PatientProfile),
    useValue: {},
 },
],
```

thanks